# clojure library project doesn't spot a syntax error during compilation

Tags: leiningen

I have a library project, that doesn't compile when I change a source file. To confirm and troubleshoot, I inserted a syntax error in the file. The following commands will detect the error:

- `lein check`
- `lein test`

Whereas `lein compile`, `lein install` and so forth won't. Even after `lein clean`. Following a `lein install`, client code using the API will crash over the syntax error.

Is this just part of clojure's compilation design?

Here's the library by the way: https://github.com/Boteval/compare-classifiers. I am facing this off a fresh clone of it.

Leiningen version: 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, yep, given clojure's lazy compilation philosophy, some compilation errors will not be detected unless the library has complete test code coverage. It's not really a "compiled language" in the "pre-compiled" sense.